# Какие неочевидные моменты регулярных выражений в javascript следует знать

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Какие неочевидные моменты регулярных выражений в javascript следует знать, чтобы корректно реализовать аналогичный движок регулярных выражений? Интересует только синтаксис (в том числе ES6), а также сопоставление с выражением и выделение групп, не замена. Предполагается полная поддержка флагов, в том числе ES6 (`u` и `y`).

Предполагаются ответы с описанием фичи и тестов (либо их описания) для её проверки.
Если предлагается код для генерации тестов, приветствуется синтаксис ES6.

Если в других языках некий синтаксис приводит к другому результату, об этом стоит сказать.

PS: Базовые тесты добавлю позже.

Comment: так в чем суть вопроса?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, перечислить малоизвестные фичи регулярных выражений. Например, то, что я привёл в ответе или [такое](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446539/178988) - пока не проверил на предмет backreference.

Comment: мысль с заголовком тогда не совпадает))

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а какие есть варианты заголовка?

Comment: `u` флаг уже есть в Babel. Вопрос ни о чем

Comment: `какие неочевидные моменты регулярных выражений в javascript следует знать` — все?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ok.

Comment: @Qwertiy вообще идея вопроса мне нравится и знания ценные. Как мне кажется, минусы из-за формы. (Я не ставил минусов)

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы забыли про `.`, которую приходится заменять на `\s\S` и.т..п. ввиду отсутствия флага `DOT_ALL`

Comment: Если очень хочется оформить вопрос-ответ - оформи в виде вопроса и **одного** ответа. В текущем виде это - неформат и оффтоп. Хотя бы по той причине, что он не дает пользоватеям выразить (не)согласие с форматом в виде плюсов и минусов (система откатывает их как серийные)

Comment: @PashaPash, система не откатывает 4 плюса, поставленные в течение минуты ответам одного пользователя на один вопрос (по крайней мере, на мете). <s>Похоже, количество поставленных тобой минусов несколько больше и затрагивает другие вопросы/ответы.</s> Про другие был неправ. В любом случае, нет причин минусовать всё подряд. Где-то на мете было решение ответы не минусовать, если вопрос не нравится.

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня откатило 3 из 4 голосов. Отобразилось как три "+1" в нотификациях - [примерно так](http://imgur.com/YaVplIK). Решения на мете по голосам не выносятся (к сожалению, или к счастью).

Comment: @PashaPash, я вижу две отмены на +12 и +10.

Comment: @Qwertiy значит не только мои голоса откатились.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Группы в обратных ссылках могут иметь номера более 100

```
`${"1".repeat(101)}2211`.match(RegExp(`${"(.)".repeat(101)}\\101`, 'g')) == '1'.repeat(100) + "22"
`${"1".repeat(101)}2211`.match(RegExp(`${"(.)".repeat(101)}\\101`)) == `${"1".repeat(100)}22${",1".repeat(100)},2`
```

Почему это особенность: [в строке замены поддерживается только 99 групп](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446539/178988).

## Все найденные вхождения имеют разный стартовый индекс

```
"123".match(/^|./g) == ",2,3"
"123".match(/(?=.)|./g) == ",,"
"123".match(/(?=3)|./g) == "1,2,"
"".match(/^|$/g) == ""
```

```
"123".match(/.|$/g) == "1,2,3,"
```

Если есть возможность выбрать пустую строку и нечто, начинающееся только за ней, то при глобальном поиске будет выбрано только что-то одно из них.

Можно заметить, что [в Си++ это не так](//ideone.com/nu0zNs) (по крайней мере, по умолчанию).

## Расширения синтаксиса регулярных выражений

Дефисы в наборах символов

```
/[\w-_]/.exec("-")[0] === "-"
```

Экранирование неслужебных символов

```
/\z/.exec("\\z")[0] === "z"
/[\z]/.exec("[\\z]")[0] === "z"
```

Некорректные управляющие последовательности

```
/\c2/.exec("\\c2")[0] === "\\c2"
```

Некорректные юникодные последовательности

```
/\u1/.exec("u1")[0] === "u1"
/[\u1]/.exec("u")[0] === "u"
```

Некорректные шестнадцатеричные последовательности

```
/\x1/.exec("x1")[0] === "x1"
/[\x1]/.exec("x")[0] === "x"
```

Неполные подшаблоны и квантификаторы

```
/x{1/.exec("x{1")[0] === "x{1"
/x]1/.exec("x]1")[0] === "x]1"
```

Восьмеричные последовательности

```
/\041/.exec("!")[0] === "!"
/[\041]/.exec("!")[0] === "!"
```

Несуществующие обратные ссылки становятся восьмеричными последовательностями

```
/\41/.exec("!")[0] === "!"
/[\41]/.exec("!")[0] === "!"
```

Источник: [ECMAScript 6 compatibility table](//kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) (kangax).